# Python 3.x replace() with index

Tags: python, string, function, replace

A question I came up with:

I'm trying to write a function that replaces the first and the fourth letter of a word with the same letter just capitalized.
Currently I am working with the string.replace() method. It works great for most of the time, except when there is an equal letter to the one on the fourth place before it. 
Example: "bananas"
What I would expect the program to do is to return "BanAnas" but for a reason it return "BAnanas". If I use the word "submarine" it would just work fine, "SubMarine".

The code I wrote is this:

```
def old_macdonald(name):
    name = name.replace(name[0], name[0].upper(), 1)
    name = name.replace(name[3], name[3].upper(), 1)
    return name
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Adjust your code. Add 4 spaces in beginning of each code line.

Comment: Run over each character and make it uppercase if the index matches: `[c.upper() if i in (0, 3) else c for i, c in enumerate('Bananas')]`. Simple thing left to do is [joning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) that back to a string (I'll leave that for exercise).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `name.replace(name[3], name[3].upper(), 1)` looks for the first character matching `name[3]`. Stop using replace altogether, chop up your string by slicing.